# Deleting artifacts from GIT

Tags: git

I'm using GIT but I'm having the problem that I do not have enough space. I need only to save the latest 3 versions of an artifact.
I do not only upload source code, zip, ear... are allowed.

I found how GIT stores the file, 
**https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Los-entresijos-internos-de-Git-Los-objetos-Git**

but each time that I modified the files in  GIT Repositoy manually it makes that the repository does not work anymore.

I found in next link how to delete those files

**https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Los-entresijos-internos-de-Git-Mantenimiento-y-recuperaci%C3%B3n-de-datos**

But I have some problem.

Imagine that I have next commits and in all of them I've modified file test.txt

commit1 -->

commit2 -->

commit3 -->

commit4 -->

commit5 -->

commit6 -->

One to the command to execute is:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch borra/fich.txt' -- commit3 ^..
```

If a execute it, I delete from commit3 to now (commit6), but I only need to delete commit3 or just from Commit3 to Commit1
Is it possible to be done?

regards
Javi

Comment: Where's the point in using git if you don't want to keep all revisions? Couldn't you just skip it?

Comment: Maybe you have some big files in it ? Create a brand new repository with the current code (but not the old revision) and make sure you have your .gitignore to ignore any big files that are not needed.

Comment: Hello,it's a good idea, but the main problem I've is that although I use gitignore, those artifacts are stored in GIT and I need to delete them, because I do not have enough space.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use git LFS or BFG to clean the repository.

### **Git Large File Storage (LFS)**

https://git-lfs.github.com/

> **Git Large File Storage (LFS)** replaces large files such as audio samples, videos, datasets, and graphics with text pointers inside Git, while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or GitHub Enterprise.

[image]

---

### BFG Repo-Cleaner

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Removes large or troublesome blobs like git-filter-branch does, but faster. And written in Scala

Comment: I've read the link but it's not what I exactly need. I need to delete some specifics artifacts related to a commit